# Iterative grep with r

Tags: r, loops, subset

Ok so thank you guy, I will start again the question:

this is my df

```
df = read.table(text = '    replicate    size   fh
ms03a_T0_r1  397.51 1099
ms03a_T0_r1  695.46    8
ms03a_T0_r1  708.76 1409
ms03a_T0_r1 1203.98  102
ms03a_T0_r2  397.52  749
ms03a_T0_r2  493.97   23
ms03a_T0_r2  538.43   12
ms03a_T0_r3  397.49  638
ms03a_T0_r3  399.84    9
ms03a_T0_r3  404.95   33
ms03a_T0_r3  406.85   40 ', header = T)

Rn <- as.numeric(length(levels(ol$replicate)))
# just to calculate the number of samples
```

From this I would like to have 3 new dataset each one that will contain only rows with *_r1 value of "replicate" variable, rows with *_r2 and rows with *_r3.

I thought to did this whit these commands:

```
for (i in 1:Rn){

  x <- df[as.character(sub('.*_r', '', as.character(replicate))) %in% i];

  outfile <- paste("rep_",i,"_edited.txt",sep="")
  write.table(x,quote=FALSE,sep=", ",outfile)
}
```

but I am able to get .txt outputs and not df objects in r. In this way then I will have to import them again in r to move on the next step of my "script", and I have no idea how set r for import them automatically

Comment: `[i]_subsetted` is not a valid R name. What is that supposed to be? What is `otus_list`? What is `replicate`? What is your expected output?

Comment: [i]_subsetted should be the output df for the subsetted rows. Sorry otus_list is just the name of the main data frame. I would like to have (for the present main df) 3 new df: one with *_r1 rows, one with *_r2 rows and one with *_r3 rows

Comment: In that case, eddi's final suggestion using `split` is probably what you want. But please do read `?make.names` so that you can at least know what are valid variable names in R.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you want this:

```
df = read.table(text = '    replicate    size   fh
  ms03a_T0_r1  397.51 1099
  ms03a_T0_r1  695.46    8
  ms03a_T0_r1  708.76 1409
  ms03a_T0_r1 1203.98  102
  ms03a_T0_r2  397.52  749
  ms03a_T0_r2  493.97   23
  ms03a_T0_r2  538.43   12
  ms03a_T0_r3  397.49  638
  ms03a_T0_r3  399.84    9
 ms03a_T0_r3  404.95   33
 ms03a_T0_r3  406.85   40 ', header = T)

library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df)

special.ids = c(1,3)
dt[as.numeric(sub('.*_r', '', as.character(replicate))) %in% special.ids]
#     replicate    size   fh
#1: ms03a_T0_r1  397.51 1099
#2: ms03a_T0_r1  695.46    8
#3: ms03a_T0_r1  708.76 1409
#4: ms03a_T0_r1 1203.98  102
#5: ms03a_T0_r3  397.49  638
#6: ms03a_T0_r3  399.84    9
#7: ms03a_T0_r3  404.95   33
#8: ms03a_T0_r3  406.85   40
```

Note, `as.character` is needed because `read.table` converts strings to factors by default. You may not need that for you actual data if it's already strings.

Upon second reading, maybe you want this?

```
split(df, sub('.*_r', '', as.character(df$replicate)))
```

OP - you need to fix your question.

Comment: now I get this error..  > for (i in 1:Rn){
+   ol[as.numeric(sub('.*_r', '', as.character(replicate))) %in% input_name[i]]->a[i]
+   }
There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
Messaggi di avvertimento:
1: In `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, i, value = structure(list( ... :
  Supplied 60 items to be assigned to 1 items of column 'replicate' (59 unused)..

Comment: @LucaZoccarato try posting the code and the error in the question, it's nearly impossible to read the comment; also, if you make your question self-contained and reproducible you'll generally get much better answers (e.g. right now I'm still unsure what exactly you want to achieve; and don't forget @joran's point that `[i]_subsetted` is not a valid R name)